# AMI send SMS C#

Tags: c#, asterisk, sms

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь отправлять СМС через AMI из службы написанной на C#.
Авторизация выполяентся, а вот при выполнении команды на отправку пишет "Permission denied"

```
var manager = new AsterNET.Manager.ManagerConnection("192.168.0.14", 5038, "api2", "test2019");
manager.KeepAlive = true;
manager.Login();    
if (manager.IsConnected())
{
   AsterNET.Manager.Action.CommandAction cmdAction = new AsterNET.Manager.Action.CommandAction(); 
   cmdAction.Command = @"Action: smscommand
   command: gsm send sms 2 89525420188 ""test"" 2222";
   var response = manager.SendAction(cmdAction);
}
```

Пробовал через PuTTY с этого же компьютера этой же командой слать СМС - отправляется(всё хорошо работает). 
P.S. железка yeastar TG100.